# What kind of resampling will give highest quality when building pyramids?

Tags: qgis, raster, image-pyramids

The resampling setting of the pyramids builder of QGIS povides several ways to do so: nearest, average, gauss, cubic, average_mp, average_magphase and mode. I am not a specialist in the subject. I

What way of resampling renders the highest output quality, no matter the output size?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what all of them do exactly, but I can offer some assistance.

Nearest performs no filtering. Output pixels will always have the value of an input pixel (the nearest input pixel, hence the name). This creates aliasing, and is fast but low quality. However, if for your purpose, your resized image must only contain values from the input image, this would be an option (e.g. if the raster is discrete code values and not continuous data). Otherwise, it is a poor choice.

The others use different filtering algorithms - ways of combining multiple input pixels into the output pixel. Every filtering algorithm is a compromise between sharpness, smoothness, aliasing, speed, and artifacts, so there isn't really a "best".

If you want the simple answer, cubic is generally a good compromise. It is smooth, tolerably sharp, minimal aliasing and artifacts.

Answer (score -2):

[image]I have attached a link from GDAL documentation that has the most information I could find on how each raster resampling method works.

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html

[Check this link for more detail on each resampling algorithm](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html)

Comment: Please include more information in you answer. You can see here how to write a proper answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)